# SQL Server Replication Requires the actual server name

Tags: sql-server, sql, connection

How Hard can it be?
Ive spent the last 4 hours googling just to find either nothing works, or people randomly posting information that 'sounds good'

My setup:

Two SQL2012 Servers, in two different locations (UK and US), Using Merge to transfer data between the two.

The UK server is going to be subscriber, From the UK server I can remotely connect to the US Server.
However when setting up the subscriber and adding the US sql credentials I get

SQL Server – “SQL Server replication requires the actual server name to make a connection to the server. Connections through a server alias, IP address, or any other alternate name are not supported. Specify the actual server name, ‘{ServerABC}’. (Replication.Utilities)”

So I added a record onto my host file (on the UK server) to map Ip to ServerABC
I can ping "ServerABC"

I try to connect again to ServerABC, and get the same error.

if I do a select @@servername = "ServerABC"

What am I doing wrong?, ive spent so much time on this not getting anywhere - so frustrating!
Please help

Comment: Under SQL Configuration Manager>SQL Server Network Configuration, have you allowed Named Pipes to be enabled? In addition to this, run SELECT @@SERVERNAME and see if that matches the computer name

Comment: Named pipes enabled, do I run the select @@servername on the subscriber or the pub?

Comment: Ok running select @@servername on the publisher (US server) returns SERVERNAME\SQL2012

Comment: Run this on both just to be sure. Can you confirm "SQL2012" is the computer name itself as well?

Comment: Ok im totally confused.

Comment: The Published server Name is "ServerName"

Comment: it has a instance called "SQL2012"

Comment: select @@servername on the publisher (US server) returns SERVERNAME\SQL2012

Comment: running select @@servername on the subscriber returns "SubscriberNamne\MSINSTANCE"

Comment: What value is getting passed in for @subscriber in the call to sp_addsubscription? If you're doing this through the wizard, choose to generate a script rather than have the wizard actually create the subscription.

Comment: Sorry i dont understand, ive setup the publication on the pub server, and now on the subscriber im trying to add the subscription via the wizard, but cant connect to the pub

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212032/sql-server-replication-requires-the-actual-server-name-to-make-a-connection-to-t